# Does anyone know the source code of "setSelection" in Android EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection

[image]

I want to highlight a part of EditText with ImageSpan in it, but BackgroundSpan makes no effect to ImageSpan. I think of the function: setSelection. I want to hightlight the EditText but not select.

I think I can learn from the Source Code of setSelection, Could anyone help me or provide the Source Code of setSelection to me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are the source code

```
  /**
     * Set the selection anchor to <code>start</code> and the selection edge
     * to <code>stop</code>.
     */
    public static void setSelection(Spannable text, int start, int stop) {
        // int len = text.length();
        // start = pin(start, 0, len);  XXX remove unless we really need it
        // stop = pin(stop, 0, len);

        int ostart = getSelectionStart(text);
        int oend = getSelectionEnd(text);

        if (ostart != start || oend != stop) {
            text.setSpan(SELECTION_START, start, start,
                         Spanned.SPAN_POINT_POINT|Spanned.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE);
            text.setSpan(SELECTION_END, stop, stop,
                         Spanned.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        }
    }



   /**
     * Move the cursor to offset <code>index</code>.
     */
    public static final void setSelection(Spannable text, int index) {
        setSelection(text, index, index);
    }
```

See full source [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/text/Selection.java/?v=source)

Comment: I copy the code from the source code, but it doesn't make effect, I don't know why... Could you help me? Look at the code downstairs